# Hitting time for a random walk on the grid

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the grid on $n^2$ nodes composed of points $x$ and $y$ with coordinates in the set  $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, and consider the discrete-time Markov chain which transitions to a random neighbor at each step. Up to a constant factor, what is the hitting time from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$?

A resistance based analysis does not seem to solve this, as resistances capture commute time, not hitting time, and I do not see any argument to ensure that hitting times will be symmetric on this graph. The worst-case hitting time is $O(n^2 \log n)$ on this graph which can be proven by looking at resistances (see [this paper](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ruzzo/papers/resist.pdf)), but I'm interested in the scaling with $|x_1 - x_2|$ and $|y_1 - y_2|$. It seems natural to guess the answer is $\Theta \left( (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 \right)$ with some log factors but I'm not sure how to prove this. I also wonder if there is a neat way to prove such statement - a resistance analysis for the commute time allows us to avoid messing around with a system of equations; does a similar tool exist for hitting time?

Comment: Why are you sure the worst-case "hitting time" (I assume that just means transit time from $(x_1, y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$) is $O(n^2)$?  For the symmetric random walk on the one-dimensional line, the expected transit time from $1$ to $n$ is already $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @BrianTung-  I edited the question with a bit more detail, and added in a missing log factor.